# Set bold and italic style in a textview with custom font (Programatically)

Tags: java, android, fonts

I have a textview and I want it to be bold and italic. I apply my custom font but just let me do it either bold or italic. How can I apply the 2 styles at the same time to my textview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have a font which is both bold and italic, that's how fonts work. Unfortunately Android cannot just combine those as it's not that easy, so you need to have your own file.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried to set in the XML file:

```
android:textStyle="bold|italic"
```

Programatically:

```
textView.setTypeface(yourTypeFace, Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC);
```

Example:

[image]

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.fontapp.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/normal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        android:textSize="16sp"
         />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bold"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/italic"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        android:textSize="16sp"
    />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/boldItalic"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Main Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/bebas_neue_regular.ttf");

        TextView tvNormal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.normal);
        tvNormal.setTypeface(font);

        TextView tvBold = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.bold);
        tvBold.setTypeface(font, Typeface.BOLD);

        TextView tvItalic = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.italic);
        tvItalic.setTypeface(font, Typeface.ITALIC);


        TextView tvBoth = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.boldItalic);
        tvBoth.setTypeface(font, Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC);
    }
}
```

Comment: But I applied my custom font(with ttf files ) (programmatically). And I want to show my textview with bold and italic with using this resources files

Comment: I use my own font. I mean I have external .ttf files containing my custom font . As far as I know, if you want to put your custom font one of the views, you have to do it programatically (using typeface and loading the path where your .ttf file is and set it). But I can only do it bold or italic, not the 2 styles at the same time

Comment: Did you see the update? 'yourTypeFace' is your font.

Comment: Sorry buddy, it's not the answer. Thank you

Comment: Buddy, I added a working example with a regular ttf font